# Setting a UICollectionViewLayout subclass in a storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using a storyboard for my project and I want to have a scene that's a `UICollectionViewController` sub class, who's `UICollectionView` uses a `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass.

I've set this up in a storyboard, and I'm trying to change the "Custom Class" of the collection view's layout instance.

Here's a screen grab of the layout object that I have selected in the storyboard:

[image: Storyboard object tree with <code>UICollectionViewLayout</code> selected]

Here's a screen grab of storyboard's "Identity" inspector pane showing the "Custom Class" field that I am changing (it's at the top):

[image: Storyboard Identity inspector showing "Custom Class"]

When I try to change the "Custom Class", I can change type stuff in, but after saving, the it reverts  back to being the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. If I run the project, the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` gets used even though it's not the custom class I have set.

How can I set a custom layout class, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The approach you've used would usually let you change the class of an instance in a storyboard. However, for a `UICollectionView`, you need to do something slightly different.

Instead of selecting the `UICollectionViewLayout` instance itself and adjusting its custom class parameter, select the **`UICollectionView`** instance, as show in this screen grab:

[image: Storyboard object tree with <code>UICollectionView</code> instance selected]

Now, in the storyboard inspector, select the "Attributes" inspector pane for the `UICollectionView` instance. You'll see something like this:

[image: Storyboard Attributes inspector with "Flow" selected]

You need to change the "Layout" field combo box so that instead of "Flow" being selected, "Custom" is selected. A text field will then be appear to set your `UICollectionViewLayout` custom subclass, like this:

[image: Storyboard Attributes inspector with "Custom" selected]

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear explanation.  This inconsistency in the way custom classes are selected for layouts stumped me 2 days. :(

Comment: :-) I'm glad you've got the solution now, but worry you had to search a few days – it took me a while too! I've got the habit of checking S.O. if anything takes me more than a few minutes to work out. Then at least you know if this is something only you've found an issue with, or whether there's a known solution!